Instantiate objects recursively in an object tree Typescript
I recieve an object from my Java server that contains a list of Files and a list of Groups. The corresponding Typescript object is:
export class Group {
  files: File[];
  groups: Group[];

  constructor(group: Group) {...}
}

In typescript I need a method to traverse the entire group tree. I've created that method and added it to Group:
class Group {
  files: File[];
  groups: Group[];

  constructor(group: Group) {...}

  traverse(callback: (g: Group) => void) {
        callback(this);
        if (this.groups?.length) {
            this.groups.forEach(undergroup => {
                undergroup.traverse(callback);
            });
        }
  }
}

And I can call group.traverse(<some callback>) by first instantiating the root node in the group tree with let group = new Group(<response from server>).
The problem is that when I call traverse() on the root node and it tries to access traverse() on all the others nodes of the tree, they have not been instantiated yet and don't contain the traverse() method.
Is there a way in Typescript to automatically map each node in the group tree to new instances of Group? I.e. when I recieve the serialized response from my server, the group and all its subgroups are instantiated with new Group(...).
Or is there another way to solve this?

The problem is not with your traverse method. Please post in what format you are getting the response from the server, and your constructor implementation - that is the one you'll need to change. No, there is no way to have TypeScript do this automatically, you'll have to write and call the instantiation code yourself.

You can introduce an interface for you data, and then implement your class with it and declaring a more specific groups property and properly instantiate all children groups recursively within the constructor:
Playground
interface GroupData {
  name: string;
  groups?: GroupData[]
};

interface Group extends GroupData{};
class Group{
  declare groups?: Group[];
  constructor(group: GroupData){
    Object.assign(this, group, group.groups && {groups: group.groups.map(g => new Group(g))});
  }
  traverse(callback: (g: Group) => void) {
        callback(this);
        if (this.groups?.length) {
            this.groups.forEach(undergroup => {
                undergroup.traverse(callback);
            });
        }
  }
}

const data = {name: 'root', groups:[{name: 'child1', groups: [{name: 'child2'}]}]};

const group = new Group(data);
group.traverse(group => console.log(group.name));


Thanks! The constructor was exactly what I was looking for.

@cloudhorn i've removed implements Group since the interface and class declarations are merged.

construct as you go
Start with a type to model the server data -
type GroupType = {
  files?: File[]
  groups?: GroupType[]
}

const data: GroupType = {
  files: [new File([], "File 1"), new File([], "File 2")],
  groups: [
    {
      files: [new File([], "File 3")],
    },
    {
      groups: [
        {
          files: [new File([], "File 4")],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}

Now make Group an implementation of GroupType. As for the traverse function, don't worry that the subgroups are not Group objects. Simply construct them as you traverse -
class Group implements GroupType {
  files?: File[]
  groups?: GroupType[]
  constructor(group: GroupType) {
    Object.assign(this, group)
  }
  traverse(callback: (g: Group) => void) {
    callback(this)
    this.groups?.forEach(g => {
      new Group(g).traverse(callback) // ✅
    })  
  }
}

TypeScript Playground
new Group(data).traverse(g => console.log(g.files?.map(f => f.name)))

["File 1", "File 2"]
["File 3"] 
undefined 
["File 4"] 

a refinement
I think a different implementation of traverse could be more useful to you -
class Group implements GroupType {
  files?: File[]
  groups?: GroupType[]
  constructor(group: GroupType) {
    Object.assign(this, group)
  }
  traverse<T>(callback: (g: Group) => T[]): T[] {
    return callback(this).concat(
      this.groups?.flatMap(g => new Group(g).traverse(callback)) ?? [],
    )
  }
}

TypeScript Playground
console.log(
  new Group(data).traverse(g => g.files?.map(f => f.name) ?? []),
)

["File 1", "File 2", "File 3", "File 4"] 

ultimate freedom
Or perhaps a generator interface is more liberating -
class Group implements GroupType {
  files?: File[]
  groups?: GroupType[]
  constructor(group: GroupType) {
    Object.assign(this, group)
  }
  *[Symbol.iterator](): Generator<Group> {
    yield this
    if (this.groups)
      for (const g of this.groups)
        yield* new Group(g)

  }
}

TypeScript Playground
for (const g of new Group(data))
  console.log(g.files?.map(f => f.name))

["File 1", "File 2"]
["File 3"] 
undefined 
["File 4"] 

Generators are very flexible -
console.log(
  Array.from(new Group(data), g => g.files?.map(f => f.name)),
)

[["File 1", "File 2"], ["File 3"], undefined, ["File 4"]]

console.log(
  Array.from(new Group(data), g => g.files?.map(f => f.name) ?? []).flat(1),
)

["File 1", "File 2", "File 3", "File 4"] 

go class-less
In the time of modules, using a class has largely gone out of style. Classes offer no clear advantages and, as you can see, have a tendency to get in your way. Chances are you are using a class because you are more comfortable writing Java or C#. Try using a plain type -
type Group = {
  files?: File[]
  groups?: Group[]
}

const data: Group = { ... } // same data

Write a plain, module-level traverse function that operates on your type -
function *traverse(g: Group): Generator<Group> {
  yield g
  if (g.groups)
    for (const h of g.groups)
      yield* traverse(h)
}

TypeScript Playground
for (const g of traverse(data))
  console.log(g.files?.map(f => f.name))

["File 1", "File 2"]
["File 3"] 
undefined 
["File 4"] 

required fields
In the above examples, the files and groups fields are optional. This allows the server to omit the fields, but it adds many null checks to the code. Consider making the fields required -
type Group = {
  files: File[]
  groups: Group[]
}

Now a Group object must include the files and groups fields -
const data: Group = {
  files: [new File([], "File 1"), new File([], "File 2")],
  groups: [
    {
      files: [new File([], "File 3")],
      groups: [], // ✅
    },
    {
      files: [], // ✅
      groups: [
        {
          files: [new File([], "File 4")],
          groups: [], // ✅
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}

No null checks -
function *traverse(g: Group): Generator<Group> {
  yield g
  for (const h of g.groups)
    yield* traverse(h)
}

for (const g of traverse(data))
  console.log(g.files.map(f => f.name))

TypeScript Playground
